# Как подключить SQLite3 к C++ CRL проекту?

Tags: c++, winforms, sqlite3

У меня есть проект на Windows Forms, C++/CLI . К нему нужно подключить SQLite3. И тут к меня начались проблемы
Сначала я просто скачал исходный код, положил его в папку, подключил хедер где нужно и включил в проект .с файл. В консольном приложении все так и сработало, но в приложении WinForms нет, т. к. .с файлы нельзя компилить с флагом /clr. Может, можно отдельно этот флаг убрать в одном файле и компилировать его как простой C++?
Я пробовал подключить lib, которую сгенерировал из консоли Visual studio, пробовал через настройки и через pragma comment, вылезала куча ошибок линковки (при попытке открыть базу данных, если просто создать sqlite3* db то все компилировалось). Я думаю, что я сделал что-то не то с подключением, и проблема не в коде, но если нужно будет, то я снова создам такую же ситуацию и скину все ошибки.